# Is SPA still working for MVC4 RC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-spa

I am little confused regarding this matter. I understand that VS had a SPA template for MVC4 beta but not for MVC4 RC. But http://www.asp.net/single-page-application says I can install SPA with nuget package after installing MVC4 RC. Does this mean that SPA is still working for MVC4 RC? I am asking this because [some discussions over web](http://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/discussions/358133/) indicated the opposite. Any clue will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The latest ASP.NET SPA release (Beta) is not compatible with ASP.NET MVC4 RC (and later) but you can built your application with older NuGet packages or modyfi current sources of ASP.NET SPA to work with ASP.NET MVC 4 RC. Here you can find some how-to for those solutions:

- [Building Single Page Apps with ASP.NET MVC4 - Part 5 - using ASP.NET MVC4 RC](http://bartjolling.blogspot.nl/2012/06/building-single-page-apps-with-aspnet.html)
- [DeliveryTracker with ASP.NET MVC 4 RC](http://peterporfy.wordpress.com/2012/06/18/deliverytracker-with-asp-net-mvc-4-rc/)